# Trying to get property of non-object json

Tags: php, json

I have been trying to find the error but i cannt seems to figure it out..

json:

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [url] => http://www.traviangames.com/de/
        [title] => Travian Games Magazin News Berichte Events
        [content] => Informiert euch im Travian Games Magazin Ã¼berie      
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [url] => http://www.dreamcatchergames.com/de/
        [title] => Nordic Games GmbH | Fresh From Austria
        [content] => Neues von Nordic Games? MX vs. ATV Supercross Encore rast auf current gen 
Konsolen zu! Nordic Games und Rainbow Studios bringen MX vs.
    )
```

)

And if i do

```
echo $json[0]->url;
```

I am getting non-object error.

ohh btw I am the json value using print_r.

Comment: use `echo $json[0]['url'];`

Comment: thank you so much...and sorry for the duplicate question